# python splitting string into list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string in python that I want to split into a list, however the format of the string is that it is a numbered list.

- Example string: "1. one. 2. two. 3. three." Using something like  `re.split("\d+\.", string)` works, except sometimes part of the string there are integers followed by a ".", like currency.
- Example string: "1. I have $2.2 million. 2. blah blah." This would result in breaking the "2.2 million" into a separate string.

How can I use regular expressions to go around this? Thanks.

Comment: This heavily depends on what the contents can be. Would it be enough to add a space after the dot in to your match criteria? i.e. `"\d+. "`?

Comment: @tzaman Don't forget to escape that dot: `"\d+\. "`

Comment: @tzaman yes I believe just by adding a space after dot would be enough for my use case. A backslash would be needed before the dot as well, "\d+\. " Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea of using a regex is good, and from what I understand from the examples you have given us, you are only missing some precision on your separator.
If the dot you are looking for follows the index of an item (`1. something`), then it will be followed by a space. If it is a decimal number (`2.2 million`), then it will not.

Therefore, you can split your string this way:

```py
import re

string = "1. test 2. test2 3. 3.4 million"
splitted_string = re.split("\d+\. ", string)
```

Of course, this new separator will only work if you have no other occurrences of a dot followed by a space than right after each index.

Notice I also added a backslash before the dot: in regexes, a dot can match almost any character (including a dot itself of course), but here you are specifically looking for a dot inside the string.

Comment: Thank you, I didnt think about the fact that my list items are seperated by a space. That should solve mostly everything. Also regarding the backslash before the ".", I actually do have that in my code, I think when I copy pasted it into stack overflow it got rid of it for some reason.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to vote if my answer helped you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote